# Add disabled attribute to button inside DataList using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have 3 buttons ***test1,test2,test3*** they are belong to a `DataList` and the datalist have ten or twenty raw it depends. What i want to do is on the ***test2*** and ***test3*** are having attribute `disabled` i want to remove the attribute of ***test2*** on ***test1*** click and on ***test2*** remove the attribute of ***test3*** and on ***test3*** click add the attribute to all button again.Iam able to remove and add attribute like i wish but the problem is since the button is inside the `datalist` when the ***test1*** is clicked all raws with ***test2*** is being clicked.How can i achieve it for each raw i have tried like below couldt get through

```js
$(document).on('click', '#test1', function() {
  document.getElementById('test2').removeAttribute('disabled');
})

$(document).on('click', '#test2', function() {
  var elementHtml = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]")[0].innerHTML;
  alert(elementHtml);
  addattribute(elementHtml);
});

function addattribute(test) {
  var dataidd = test;
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-idd]").addAttribute('disabled');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test1" data-id="test1" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
test1
</button>
<button id="test2" disabled="true" data-id="test1" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
test2
</button>
<button id="test3" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
compare
</button>
```

Each button in the raw have same `data-id` so i tried to use it but no luck how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `id` for buttons because there are several rows(I think raw is a misspelled word for row) in `DataList` and `id` should be only used one-time for the page. So, you can use `class` for this position.
You add `id` or `data-index` attribute to div element of each row for identifying them, but it's not required for this position. Please check the following codebase.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-test1', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.btn-test2').removeAttr('disabled');
})

$(document).on('click', '.btn-test2', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.btn-test3').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-test3', function() {
  $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<div data-index="0">
  <button class="btn-test1" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test1
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test2" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test2
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test3" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    compare
  </button>
</div>
<div data-index="1">
  <button class="btn-test1" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test1
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test2" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test2
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test3" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    compare
  </button>
</div>
...
<div data-index="9">
  <button class="btn-test1" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test1
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test2" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    test2
  </button>
  <button class="btn-test3" disabled="true" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
    compare
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: the ```data-index``` is not possible for me

Comment: You don't have to use `data-index`. Just use JQuery `siblings` function to access the other buttons under same row.